# How to check issubset for the whole words separated by commas?

Tags: python, string, set, subset

```
string = 'NotAllowed,Trinity,Allowed'

string1 = 'NotAllowed,Allowe'

name = frozenset(string1)

if name.issubset(string) == 1:
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

This produces the output of yes. But I want to check the whole word instead of letter by letter. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it your word delimiter:

```
name = frozenset(string1.split(','))

if name.issubset(string.split(',')):
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

Comment: what if there is only one word without a comma?

Comment: Then you'll get a single-element set containing that one word, which I assume it what you want

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert string in words then u can use `issubset` for that sets.

```
string_words = string.split(',')
string1_words = string1.split(',')

if set(string1_words) <= set(string_words):
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```